# Enhanced Conversions through Google Ads API not Working

Tags: java, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

We are sending enhanced conversions to Google ADS API using the Upload Click Conversions method of the API client. This is the only data we send to API. No user identifier data about customers is sent to API before that via GTM. In Google Ads UI measurements, I see that Google only shows 5% of what actual conversions are. Does this mean we need to send Google Ads API some information through GTM before we send the conversions through the API client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to provide a user identifier via GTM (before) as well.
See Instructions here:
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/11347292